# Experiencing strange behavior in Unity when rotating a 2D GameObject according to the slope it is standing on

Tags: unity, 2d, rotation, raycasting

I am trying to rotate a square GameObject, so it appears to be standing perpendicular to the slope underneath it. However, when above a slope, the square constantly "spins"; it seems like the rotation is set and then immediately set back to 0, causing it to jitter.

I am currently using a RayCast based character controller instead of rigidbody. To change the rotation, I added the follow line of code following the vertical RayCast:

```cs
if (_raycastHit)
    {
       transform.rotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(transform.up, _raycastHit.normal) * transform.rotation; 

    ...
    }
```

It calculates and rotates the square correctly, but I am not sure why it resets back to 0 every other frame. To avoid taking up too much space, the character controller I am using is hosted on GitHub [here](https://github.com/prime31/CharacterController2D/blob/master/Assets/CharacterController2D/CharacterController2D.cs). Specifically, this is in the `moveVertically()` method.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might want something as simple as:

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.forward, _raycastHit.normal);
```

Or, if you rotate your character to flip them, you can use `transform.forward` instead of `Vector3.forward`.